# Node.js server won't run after I put it in a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm just getting started with node.js, and I'm working through a tutorial. I created a server with the code here:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

When I run that with node (node server.js) it works. I can got to localhost:8888 and there is a hello world. The next step in the tutorial is creating a server module and then running it from an index.js file. I have copied the tutorial verbatim, and the code is as follows:

index.js:

```
var server = require("./server");

server.start;
```

server.js:

```
var http = require("http");

function start() {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        console.log("Request received.");
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("Hello World");
        response.end();
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

Unfortunately node when i try to run the code (node index.js), nothing happens. Going to localhost:8888 gives a can't be reached page. This is from a section in [The Node Beginner Book](http://www.nodebeginner.org/), which I recently purchased. What's going wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you sure it's `server.start;` and not `server.start();`? The former is a statement with no effect, since `start` is a function but it's not called.

Comment: You were right, that was my mistake. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the function, try:

```
server.start();
```